# new SpeechSynthesizer APIs for windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

The [SpeechSynthesizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx) class for Windows Phone 8.0 had [BookmarkReached event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.bookmarkreached(v=vs.90).ASPX) which was raised when SpeechSynthesizer encountered a bookmark.

But the new [SpeechSynthesizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx) class for Windows Phone 8.1 has no such event. And my app is really dependent on that event.

Is there any other API or workaround?